# Changing testng xml file template in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, testng, testng.xml

I'm trying to run tests in intellij behind proxy.

I get this error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:354)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:374)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:503)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:492)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:597)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1261)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1194)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1082)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1016)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1600)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1528)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.lambda$new$0(TestNGContentHandler.java:64)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.resolveEntity(TestNGContentHandler.java:117)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:111)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:1025)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1142)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1040)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:943)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:197)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:162)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:248)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:322)
    ... 3 more

Process finished with exit code -1
```

The reason this error happens is because the testng xml file that was generated by intellij, has this line on top:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
```

I want to replace "http" in "https" in the generated file template (if I use my own testng xml file, the tests can run behind proxy).

I do I change the template intellij uses?

Comment: IDEA should already use "https" in template:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-234765. What IDE. version do you use? What is your TestNG version?

Comment: I updated intellij version and it was resolved. thank you!